# Function inside function - every time?

Tags: python, performance, closures, nested-function

Let we have this code:

```
def big_function():
    def little_function():
         .......
    .........
```

The Python documentation says about `def` statement:

> A function definition is an executable statement. Its execution binds
>   the function name...

So, the question is:
Does `def little_function()` execute every time when `big_function` is invoked?
Question is about `def` statement exactly, not the `little_function()` body.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can check the bytecode with the `dis` module:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def my_function():
...     def little_function():
...             print "Hello, World!"
...     
... 
>>> dis.dis(my_function)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object little_function at 0xb74ef9f8, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (little_function)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see the code for the inner function is *compiled* only *once*. Every time you call `my_function` it is loaded and a new function object is created(in this sense the `def little_function` *is* executed every time `my_function` is called), but this doesn't add much overhead.

Comment: How do you know how much overhead executing the `MAKE_FUNCTION` byte-code instruction involves? Seems like it might require allocating memory which it typically a slow operation in most other languages.

Comment: @martineau No, there is no big memory allocation. The `MAKE_FUNCTION` op simply increases the reference code for the code object, it doesn't have to copy. Surely a new function object is created, which involves allocating a new `PyFunctionObject` but considering that *every* operation allocates python object it doesn't hurt performances "significantly"(obviously what is significant depends on the rest of the code of `my_function`).

Answer (score 8):

The code in the inner function is compiled only once, so there shouldn't be a significant runtime penalty.

Only inner's function *closure* gets updated each time the outer function is called.  See [here](http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html), for example, for more details about closures.

Here's a quick demonstration, examining the closure:

```
def f(x):
   a = []
   b = x + 1
   def g():
      print a, b
   return g

In [28]: y = f(5)

In [29]: y
Out[29]: <function __main__.g>

In [30]: y.func_closure
Out[30]: 
(<cell at 0x101c95948: list object at 0x101c3a3f8>,
 <cell at 0x101c958a0: int object at 0x100311aa0>)

In [31]: y.func_closure[1].cell_contents
Out[31]: 6
```